# In NGINX 'location ~ .*' does not match any string

Tags: nginx-location

In the following site config file i am trying to:

1. Load index.php on the first visit.
2. Load files as they appear in the /uploads/ directory.
3. Any other request should still be handled by index.php.

   ```
   server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/va/www/example;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    # index index.php;

    server_name example.dev;

    location ~ .*
    {
        try_files /dev/null @php;
    }

    location /uploads/
    {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location @php
    {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        #pretty url
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
   }
   ```

However, the last part breaks. In other words:

```
/                  works
/?test=test        works
/uploads/test.jpeg works
/random_string     does not work and returns 404 error
```

My understanding is that `location ~ .*` has no choice but to match everything. Where is the 404 error coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After working on it some more, and completely rewriting the logic, i have gotten a muse from [The MediaWiki Nginx guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Nginx). The final solution is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    root /home/va/www/example;
    
    server_name example.dev;
    
    location = /
    {
        return 301 /home;
    }
    location = /index.php
    {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        
        #pretty url
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location /uploads/
    {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires 30d;
    }
    location /
    {
        rewrite ^/(?<pagename>.*)$ /index.php;
    }
    
    location /classes/ { deny all; }
    location /config/ { deny all; }
}
```

I will then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` within PHP to route the request. Hopefully this solution will help somebody.